# Windows CreateThread within a class function call, pointer reference crash?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, reference, createthread

Below I have an `int main()` and two header files, one of which is a class for creating a thread and another which is a class called `object` that gets created within the `windows_thread` class. This really simple exercise should output 99 but instead its 1 (for some unknown reason). I also tried using a pointer to an object made by `new` which crashed when `void call()` from the function `Thread_no_1(  )` to the class `object` is made, maybe because its none existent. I hope someone could remedy this otherwise I'll just use windows threads in `int main()`.

this is the main.

```
#include "windows_thread.h"

int main()
{
    windows_thread* THREAD = new windows_thread();
    THREAD->thread();

    delete THREAD;

    return 0;
}
```

this is the windows_thread.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "object.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 255

class windows_thread
{
        object OBJECT;

    public:

        windows_thread():OBJECT(99)
        {
            //OBJECT = new object(99);

        }
        ~windows_thread()
        {
            //delete OBJECT;
        }
        void thread()
        {
            std::cout<<"void thread: "<<std::endl;
            int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;            // Data of Thread 1
            HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_1 = 0;       // variable to hold handle of Thread 1

            HANDLE Array_Of_Thread_Handles[1];   // Aray to store thread handles

    // Create thread 1.
            Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,  Wrap_Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
            if ( Handle_Of_Thread_1 == NULL)  ExitProcess(Data_Of_Thread_1);

    // Store Thread handles in Array of Thread Handles as per the requirement of WaitForMultipleObjects()
            Array_Of_Thread_Handles[0] = Handle_Of_Thread_1;


    // Wait until all threads have terminated.
            WaitForMultipleObjects( 1, Array_Of_Thread_Handles, TRUE, INFINITE);

            printf("Since All threads executed lets close their handles \n");

    // Close all thread handles upon completion.
            CloseHandle(Handle_Of_Thread_1);
        }
        void DisplayMessage (HANDLE hScreen, char *ThreadName, int Data, int Count)
        {
            TCHAR msgBuf[BUF_SIZE];
            size_t cchStringSize;
            DWORD dwChars;

    // Print message using thread-safe functions.
    //StringCchPrintf(msgBuf, BUF_SIZE, TEXT("Executing iteration %02d of %s having data = %02d \n"), Count, ThreadName, Data);
    //StringCchLength(msgBuf, BUF_SIZE, &cchStringSize);
            WriteConsole(hScreen, msgBuf, cchStringSize, &dwChars, NULL);
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1(  )
        {
            std::cout<<"Thread_no_1: "<<std::endl;
            OBJECT.call();
            //OBJECT->call();

            return 0;
        }
        static DWORD WINAPI Wrap_Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
        {
            std::cout<<"Wrap_Thread_no_1: "<<std::endl;

            windows_thread *self = reinterpret_cast<windows_thread*>(lpParam);
            self->Thread_no_1();

            return 0;
        }
};
```

next is the object.h

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include <iostream>

class object
{
        private:

            int value;

        public:

        object(int value)
        {
            std::cout<<"object::constructor: "<<std::endl;
            this->value = value;
        }
        ~object(){}
        void call()
        {
            std::cout<<"object::call(): begin"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"object::call(): end"<<std::endl;
        }
};
#endif
```

Comment: Any reason you're making a pointer in `main`?

Comment: This might do it, seeing as how you pass in a pointer to an integer: `windows_thread *self = reinterpret_cast<windows_thread*>(lpParam);
            self->Thread_no_1();`

Comment: @I suppose it could be `windows_thread THREAD;` . I tend to create objects temporarily hence a thread for temporary usage. Is there a way to free up memory the other way?

Comment: Yes, it's freed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @chris Right, but what if I need an arbitrary number of threads during runtime?

Comment: @chris I suppose thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function call:

```
Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread(
    NULL, 
    0,  
    Wrap_Thread_no_1, 
    &Data_Of_Thread_1, // <== THIS IS A POINTER TO AN int
    0, 
    NULL
    );
```

Passes `&Data_Of_Thread_1` (a pointer to an `int`) to `CreateThread()`. This is the argument that gets eventually passed to `Wrap_Thread_no_1()`.

Inside that function, you then cast that pointer to a `windows_thread*` and call a member function through it. This injects **Undefined Behavior** in your code.

You probably meant to do this instead:

```
Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0,  Wrap_Thread_no_1, this, 0, NULL);
//                                                            ^^^^
```

Comment: Agree, int Data_Of_Thread_1 is casted to windows_thread *self in function Wrap_Thread_no_1.